# How do you create a shortcut to a directory so that it opens in explorer

Tags: windows, explorer

Better yet, how can I make My Computer always open in Explorer as well?

I usually make a shortcut to my programming directories on my quick launch bar, but I'd love for them to open in Explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

explorer -d c:\path

Answer (score 4):

I use `explorer /e,c:\path`.

@harpo

`explorer -d c:\path` does not work for me (WinXP sp3).

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the win+e hotkey? It isn't quite what you want, but might be close enough.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130510

```
i.e.:
explorer /e,%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
```